# 'mblctr' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.How to fix this?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have created a button in vs to open mobility center. when i run the code it shows error 'mblctr' is not recognized,but when run the 'mblctr' in cmd it wroks fine.This is my code someone help me out

```
private: System::Void button21_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    //system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\mblctr.exe");
    system("mblctr");
 }
```

Comment: Improve the question formatting, please.

Comment: That doesn't look like C++ or C - what's that `^` doing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mblctr.exe only exists as a 64-bit application on 64-bit Windows. A 32-bit application does not see the same System32 folder as 64-bit applications. You can access the 64-bit System32 folder in 32-bit applications with the virtual sysnative folder.

```
#include <shellapi.h>
...
INT_PTR ret = (INT_PTR) ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, TEXT("mblctr.exe"), 0, 0, SW_SHOW);
if (ret <= 32)
{
    TCHAR buf[MAX_PATH];
    GetWindowsDirectory(buf, MAX_PATH);
    lstrcat(buf, TEXT("\\sysnative\\mblctr.exe")); // Hopefully this fits in MAX_PATH, you might want to check in a real program.
    ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, buf, 0, 0, SW_SHOW);
}
```

It works in cmd.exe because you are running the 64-bit version of cmd when you start it manually. If you run the 32-bit bit version of cmd.exe it will fail:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> "cmd"

```
C:\Users\Anders>%windir%\syswow64\cmd.exe
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Anders>mblctr.exe
'mblctr.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```